# If $f > 0$, $\ker(L)$ contains only constant functions, where $L = - \Delta + \nabla (- \log(f)) \cdot \nabla$ (Villani, Subsec. 7.6)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, probability-distributions, linear-transformations, optimal-transport, elliptic-operators

In subsection(s) 7.5 (and 4.1) of [*Topics in Optimal Transportation*](https://books.google.de/books?hl=en&lr=&id=NElDEAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PP1&dq=topics%20in%20optimal%20transportation&ots=G8kiA_z1Xn&sig=boVXz4suyLiPwMb4xf1bWI3NWhY#v=onepage&q&f=false), Cedric Villani states the following (I paraphrase):

> Take a probability measure $\mu \in \mathcal P_2(\mathbb R^n)$ with finite second moment and strictly positive density $f$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. Consider the linear [differential operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator)
> $$
> L := - \Delta + \nabla (- \log(f))\cdot \nabla.
> $$
> Then $L$ satisfies the following integration-by-parts formula with respect to $\mu$:
> $$
> \int_{\mathbb R^d} (L h_1)(x) h_2(x) \, \text{d}\mu(x)
> = \int_{\mathbb R^d} (L h_2)(x) h_1(x) \, \text{d}\mu(x) 
> = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \nabla h_1(x) \cdot \nabla h_2(x) \, \text{d}\mu(x) 
> $$
> for all $h_1, h_2 \colon \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ with certain regularity assumptions.
> In particular, $L$ is a non-negative self-adjoint operator on the set of those $h$ with respect to the $L^2(\mathbb R^d, d \mu)$ scalar product.

> Inspired by $\| h \|_{L^2(\mathbb R^d)}^2 = \int_{\mathbb R^d} | h(x) |^2 \, \text{d}x$ and $\| h \|_{\dot{H}^1(\mathbb R^d)}^2 = \int_{\mathbb R^d} \| \nabla h(x) \|_2^2 \, \text{d}x$ we define **weighted** square "norms"
> $$
> \| h \|_{L^2(\mathbb R^d, d \mu)}^2 = \int_{\mathbb R^d} | h(x) |^2 \, \text{d}\mu(x)
> \quad \text{and} \quad
> \| h \|_{\dot{H}^1(\mathbb R^d, d\mu)}^2 = \int_{\mathbb R^d} h(x)(L h)(x) \|_2^2 \, \text{d}\mu(x).
> $$
> Since $f > 0$ everywhere, $\ker(L)$ only contains constant functions. Under certain regularity conditions which we prefer not to discuss here, one can define the inverse $L^{-1}$ of $L$ on space of functions $h$ with $\int_{\mathbb R^d} h(x) \, \text{d}\mu(x) = 0$ and then establish
> \begin{align}
> \| h \|_{H^{-1}(\mathbb R^d, d \mu)}
> & := \sup\left\{ \int_{\mathbb R^d} h(x) k(x) \, \text{d}\mu(x): k \in \mathcal{C}_c^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n), \| k \|_{\dot{H}^1(\mathbb R^d; d\mu)} = 1 \right\} \\
> & = \int_{\mathbb R^d} h(x) (L^{-1} h)(x) \, \text{d}\mu(x),
> \end{align}
> so $H^{-1}(\mathbb R^d, d \mu)$ is dual to $\dot{H}^1(\mathbb R^d, d \mu)$.

---

**My work so far.**
I don't know how to show that $\ker(L)$ only contains constant functions, partly because I don't know on which space $L$ is defined.
If we could take $f = 1$ (we can't since then $\mu$ would not be a probability measure), then $L = - \Delta$ and surely $\ker(L)$ also contains linear functions.
If $f(x) = e^{-x^2} \in L^2(\mathbb R)$ up to a normalization constant, then $-\log(f) = x^2$ and thus $L h = - h''(x) + 2 x h'(x)$ and $L h = 0$ implies $h(x) = c_1 \text{erfi}(x) + c_2$, where erfi is the imaginary error function, according to WolframAlpha, which is not constant.

**My question.** I am wondering I what way "$\ker(L)$ contains only constant functions" is meant and how to show it.

Comment: I would assume that $L$ is defined on the space of functions that satisfy the "regularity assumptions" you mention?

Comment: @K.defaoite thanks for you comment. Unfortunately, no such regularity assumptions are described in that subsection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R \in\ker(L)$ satisfy the "certain regularity assumptions" mentioned in the OP (which certainly include differentiability). From the integration by parts formula, we get :

\begin{align*}
\|\nabla h\|^2_{L^2(\mathbb R^d,d\mu)} :&= \int_{\mathbb R^d} | \nabla h(x) |^2 \, \text{d}\mu(x) \\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^d}  \nabla h(x) \cdot \nabla h(x)\, \text{d}\mu(x) \\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^d} [L h](x)\cdot h(x) \, \text{d}\mu(x)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb R^d} 0\cdot h(x) \, \text{d}\mu(x)=0.\end{align*}

Hence $h\in\ker (L)\implies \nabla h\equiv 0$ for $\mu$-almost all $x$. Since it is said that $f>0$ everywhere and $h$ is differentiable, it follows that the kernel of $L$ only contains constant functions.

---

As for why you get that $Lh(x) \equiv 0$ for $h:x\mapsto c_1 \text{erfi}(x) + c_2$ with $c_1\ne 0$ in the case $f\propto e^{-x^2}$, my reasonable guess is that the domain of $L$ consists of functions which are square-integrable with respect to $d\mu$, which in particular implies (since $\mu$ is finite) that these functions are also absolutely integrable with respect to $d\mu$. But if $c_1\ne 0$ then your $h$ will not be absolutely integrable with respect to $d\mu$, indeed, for any $t>0$ :

$$\int_{-t}^t |\text{erfi}(x)|\ d\mu(x)=\frac2Z\int_0^t \text{erfi}(x)e^{-x^2}\ dx = Ct^2\ _2F_2\left(1,1;\frac32,2;-t^2\right)\tag 1 $$
Where $Z:=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-x^2}\ dx$, $C$ is a positive constant and $_2F_2$ is a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function). The right-hand side of $(1)$ diverges [according to wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Berfi%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29exp%5C%2840%29-%5C%2840%29Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Ca%7D%5D), thus we see that $h:x\mapsto c_1\text{erfi}(x) + c_2$ is not in the domain of $L$ for $c_1\ne 0$, and so there is no contradiction.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I only wrote "certain regularity assumptions" because in the book no conditions are mentioned that are necessary for the ibp formula to hold. Do you know what they might be?

Comment: @ViktorStein sadly I'm not sure of what Villani had in mind, as I don't have the book and I am frankly kind of new to optimal transport myself. If it can help you though, at least in the case $f\propto e^{-|x|^2} $, $L$ is the [generator of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck semigroup](https://djalil.chafai.net/blog/2016/02/13/aspects-of-the-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process/), in which case its domain of definition can be characterized. I don't have a good reference besides Theorem 2 of [these slides by Bogachev](https://irtg.math.uni-bielefeld.de/_media/bogachev-bielefeld-aug19.pdf).

Comment: In the case of arbitrary $f\propto e^{-\Phi(x)}$ I am pretty clueless, but maybe Bogachev's argument, which relies on finding an orthonormal basis of $L^2(d\mu)$, can be adapted. Smooth compactly support functions will do the trick in general (as these are sufficient for the integration by parts formula to work), but the result I quote suggests that the domain of $L$ is larger. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will chime in.

Comment: Maybe $h$ has to be in the weighted Sobolev space $H^1(\mu)$ of $L^2(\mu)$ integrable functions whose (weak) derivative is in $L^2(\mu)$ as well?

Comment: Yes I think that would make sense.